# Feign Client called from a thread + Spring Security

Tags: spring-security, spring-cloud, java-threads, netflix-feign

I have situation where I call a feign client. It works fine, until I try putting the feign client inside a thread (simplified version):

```
@Autowired
UsuarioFeign feignUserClient;

....

final Runnable t = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            feignUserClient.findByEmail("someEmail@address.com");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
new Thread(t).start();
```

When I try to do it, I get (printed by the real version, not the simplified one above):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at br.alfa.tutoria.AlfaTutoriaApplication$1.apply(AlfaTutoriaApplication.java:46)
at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.targetRequest(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:158)
at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:88)
at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:76)
at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:103)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy246.findByEmail(Unknown Source)
at br.alfa.tutoria.service.impl.TutoriaServiceImpl.atribuiFuncaoTutor(TutoriaServiceImpl.java:285)
at br.alfa.tutoria.service.impl.TutoriaServiceImpl$2.run(TutoriaServiceImpl.java:270)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The `feignUserClient` is @Autowired (I've tried turn it final, and inject it using a constructor, but it made no difference - anyway, it's value is not null when the code execute).

More info:

#### Feign Interface:

```
@FeignClient(name = "authUsers", url = br.alfa.tutoria.config.Url.AUTH_SERVER)
public interface UsuarioFeign {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/user-search-by-email", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public User findByEmail(String email);
}
```

The other class, which calls the feign interface... it doesn't matter. I tried it in several diferent classes (all of them annotated with `@RestController` or `@Service`). It just stop working if I call the `UsuarioFeign.findByEmail` from a thread.

Comment: Can you add the entire `AlfaTutoriaApplication` class?

Comment: Just did, @ryan. I'm trying to track down the issue. I build up two simple feign applications with simple threads. It worked. So simple threads not the problem. I'm still working on it. Now I'm going to update Spring boot and, next, look for nested threads.

Comment: I deleted the `AlfaTutoriaApplication` class from the topic, @ryan. In fact it gave me an important clue about what the real problem was (but thank you for asking it - the simple act of copying-&-pasting called my atention to the Security part).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end, the problem had to do with Spring Security Context. By design, "*the Security is stored in a per Thread basis*" according to [Spring Security docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/concurrency.html). That means that if you need something like the security context in a new thread, you won't get it.

In the docs you can find a way to transfer it as a parameter to a new thread:

```
Runnable originalRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // invoke secured service
    }
};

SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
DelegatingSecurityContextRunnable wrappedRunnable =
    new DelegatingSecurityContextRunnable(originalRunnable, context);

new Thread(wrappedRunnable).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContext;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestAttributes;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder;

public class SecurityContextRunnable implements Runnable {
    private Runnable runnable;
    private RequestAttributes requestAttributes;
    private SecurityContext securityContext;
    private SecurityContext originalSecurityContext;

    private SecurityContextRunnable(Runnable runnable) {
        this(runnable, RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes());
    }

    private SecurityContextRunnable(Runnable runnable, RequestAttributes requestAttributes) {
        this(runnable, requestAttributes, null);
    }

    private SecurityContextRunnable(Runnable runnable, RequestAttributes requestAttributes, SecurityContext securityContext) {
        try {
            if (securityContext == null) {
                securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        this.runnable = runnable;
        this.requestAttributes = requestAttributes;
        this.securityContext = securityContext;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        this.originalSecurityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        try {
            SecurityContextHolder.setContext(securityContext);
            RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(requestAttributes);
            runnable.run();
        } finally {
            SecurityContext emptyContext = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
            if (emptyContext.equals(originalSecurityContext)) {
                SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
            } else {
                SecurityContextHolder.setContext(originalSecurityContext);
            }
            this.originalSecurityContext = null;
        }
    }

    public static SecurityContextRunnable create(Runnable runnable) {
        return new SecurityContextRunnable(runnable);
    }

    public static SecurityContextRunnable create(Runnable runnable, RequestAttributes requestAttributes) {
        return new SecurityContextRunnable(runnable, requestAttributes);
    }

    public static SecurityContextRunnable create(Runnable runnable, RequestAttributes requestAttributes, SecurityContext securityContext) {
        return new SecurityContextRunnable(runnable, requestAttributes, securityContext);
    }

}


Runnable originalRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            feignUserClient.findByEmail("someEmail@address.com");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};

SecurityContextRunnable wrappedRunnable = SecurityContextRunnable.create(originalRunnable);
new Thread(wrappedRunnable).start();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't just throw your source code here. Be nice and try to give a nice description to your answer, so that others will like it and upvote it. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)